# Robotframework: Check if a response is an element of a list of correct responses

Tags: robotframework

I have a test in Robot where the server returns a response in which there are a number of elements that can be in any order. I therefore am not just trying to check a returned string against a single correct response. Instead, I would like the test to pass if the response is in a list of possible correct responses.

For example, on running the test, the result could be `{"red": "yes", "blue": "no"}`, or it could be `{"blue": "no", "red": "yes"}`. Either should pass.

Is there a way of doing this simply?

(I don't want to sort the result before performing the check)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using [Dictionaries Should Be Equal](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Dictionaries%20Should%20Be%20Equal) keyword:

```
${dictA} =    Create Dictionary    red=yes    blue=no
${dictB} =    Create Dictionary    blue=no    red=yes
Dictionaries Should Be Equal    ${dictA}    ${dictB}
```